# Java: When to use fields vs. arguments?

Tags: java, coding-style, methods

My current IVR app uses a wrapper class with several methods to call a web service and then parse its results.  Each class has a single "invoke" method which calls the web service, and then calls subsequent submethods to break up the parsing into logical chunks.

Whenever a new input argument is needed in one or more of the submethods, the previous developer would add it as an argument on the invoke, and then add it as an argument on the submethods.

Is this the proper way to do this, or would it be *better* to set a field on the class, and then reference that whenever necessary?

Instead of:

```
 invoke (oldField1, oldField2, newField1)  
 submethod1 (results, oldField1, oldField2, newField1)  
 submethod2 (results, oldField1, oldField2, newField1)
```

Should it be:

```
 invoke(oldField1, oldField2, newField1){
   OldField1=oldField1
   OldField2=oldField2
   NewField1=newField1
 }
 submethod1(results)
 submethod2(results)
```

Or even:

```
 new (oldField1, oldField2, newField1){
   OldField1=oldField1
   OldField2=oldField2
   NewField1=newField1
 }
 invoke()
 submethod1(results)
 submethod2(results)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The first solution allows making the object stateless, and allows using a unique instance for all the invocations, even in parallel.

The third one allows making the object stateful but immutable. It could be used for several invocations using the same set of fields, even in parallel (if made immutable).

Both of these solutions are acceptable. The less state an object has, the easiest it is to use it, particularly in a multi-thread environment.

The less mutable an object is, the easiest it is to use it.

The second one makes it a stateful mutable object, which can't be used by several threads (without synchronization). It looks less clean than the other two to me.

Answer (score 1):

My general rule is to avoid statefulness in a service-oriented class whenever possible. Although Java doesn't really support functional programming per-se, the simplest and most scalable implementation is your first approach, which uses no member variables.

If your goal is to avoid frequent changes to method signatures, you could try to use a more generic field encapsulation:

```
public class Invoker {
    public static void invoke(ResultContainer result, List<String> parameters) {
        submethod1(result, parameters);
        submethod2(result, parameters);
    }
}
```

I would also recommend that you take a look at the [Decorator design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) for more ideas.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on if your argument is data or identifying a mode/switch.

I suggest one argument for the data structure type and another argument that contains the enum types of different operations.

And then based on your enum type or mode of operation you can choose a strategy on which class  to execute.

To restrict this increasing argument approach, you could provide an interface. And force the implementation to adhere to that.